# Data Source for SWF Chart

Tags: flash, reverse-engineering

Hello
How would one go about reverse engineering a page such as the [this one](http://s.xe.com/20100208/currencycharts/chrt.8.swf) to work out where the data being used to create the chart comes from?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best SWF decompiler I know of is from HP and is called [SWFScan](https://h30406.www3.hp.com/campaigns/2009/wwcampaign/1-5TUVE/index.php?key=swf).  You have to register with HP to download it, but it works well.

I ran it on the link you provided, and decompiled it.  You would have to look through the source code and try to determine where it is being loaded.

You can also use a network monitor.  For Flash, I recommend [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) which is a debugging proxy and will show you all the websites you are accessing through your browser.  It also understands the Flash AMF protocol.